# Delphi & Google drive - API info

Tags: delphi, google-drive-api

*You may crucify me for this, but the link for "Support - Drive API" on the Google drive SDK website itself took me here - on the SO forum to put up a new question, so thats exactly what I'm gonna do as I didnt find any other useful info elsewhere.*

Is there any way at all, and if so, where could I get any documentation/help/examples for accessing Google Drive from my delphi application? The online SDK seems to only allow use for iOS, Web and Android devices... no Desktop api available?

I know about TAdvGDrive component that comes with Tms Cloud Pack, but am looking into a solution that wouldn't cost me 100$ to get it done.

Comment: I think you have to come in via the web api. Do be prepared for Google to pull the rug from under you at regular intervals. It's like the Wild West out there in Google API land!

Comment: I was thinking in such direction but was afraid it would be, as you described, wild west....   I really dont get how they haven't provided this....   .. and even less why their stock app has less than basic functionalities, and lacks very basic functions like folders/subfolders selection for sync. Shame...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this using REST (unfortunately I can't post the code here because was a private work for a customer). Anyway you can check for the Google Drive API [REST documentation here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/). Starting with Delphi  XE5 you can use the [REST Client Library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/REST_Client_Library) (If you are using an older version of Delphi you can use Indy or another library to build a basic REST library). I'm not aware of any sample about using The Google Drive SDK REST and Delphi, but you can start reading the [`RESTDemo Sample`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/RESTDemo_Sample) App, and check the Google documentation.

**UPDATE (01/03/2018) - LINK RESTORED**

I just found an article to access the Google Drive SDK using REST and Delphi [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.webdelphi.ru%2F2013%2F09%2Fdelphi-xe5-rest-client-library%2F).